# Replace string in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a below JSON

```
{
    "query": "select Owner.Name, Owner.Id from custom_table where CreatedDate >= '2020-01-01'"
}
```

How can I replace `'2020-01-01'` with the values stored in a variable `startDate`?

Comment: You don't need to add any quotes to the date literals. Just put the date in UTC format.

Comment: Are you accepting queries over an API endpoint? There's out-of-the-box APIs that do that at much lower security risk, if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be simply accomplished with a replace using a regex

This regex select a string in format `'XXXX-XX-XX'` where X are numbers from 0 to 9

```js
const regex = /'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'/gm;
const str = ` select Owner.Name, Owner.Id from custom_table where CreatedDate >= '2020-01-01'`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', startDate);
```

I always use https://regex101.com/codegen?language=javascript to develop my regex